# Cordova Android Uncaught Function Error

Tags: android, cordova

I'm currently using PhoneGap 2.7.0 on my project and code runs without error on iOS.When I try to run the same code on android (with the exception of the Cordova javascript file, which I know is different for Android) I'm getting this error:

```
05-21 22:02:25.630    1663-1663/com.###.### D/Cordova: onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
05-21 22:02:25.640    1663-1663/com.###.### D/CordovaLog: Uncaught Function required as first argument!
05-21 22:02:25.640    1663-1663/com.###.### E/Web Console: Uncaught Function required as first argument! at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.7.0.js:627
```

Here is the JavaScript I'm using in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var app;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function()
{
    app = new AppWrapper();
}, false);
</script>
```

I'm not sure what the issue is.I had this issue before but it has resolved itself in the past (black magic?).Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After employing Ripple to debug this issue (highly recommended), I found a pointer to an undefined function being applied to an event listener (so, not specific to the deviceready call).

For future developers: check to make sure **all** of your "addEventListener" calls are pointing to existing functions. Seems obvious, but it happens.

Answer (score 4):

Check if you had specified the right context of the callback function in your code.

Make sure that you don't use "this" in callback function. For example,

```
var app = {
   init : function() {
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.deviceready, false);
   },

   deviceready : function() {
       app.appWrapper = this.createAppWrapper();//watch out who is "this", you should use "app" but not "this"
   },

   createAppWrapper : function() {
      return new AppWrapper();
   }
};

app.init();
```